# Query regarding nature of a statement. On-topic here?

Tags: discussion

Question regarding a statement one reads somewhere and is not sure as to what meaning to derive from it, or has derived a meaning from it but would like to be sure whether the derivation is correct or not.

Are questions of this nature welcome here? Or [elu](http://english.stackexchange.com) would be better suited? Or neither?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**; questions asking "please explain the meaning of this statement" or "did I understand this statement correctly" are not on topic here - such questions are off-topic because they don't deal with writing, and additionally aren't very useful to anybody beside the original poster.

I don't know ELU's policy regarding such questions, but they may be more appropriate there. Feel free to ask on their meta :)